# First Posts review queue is not showing first questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I noticed that the First Posts review queue on [Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com) is no longer showing questions. The [most recent first question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26154/how-to-remove-construction-adhesive-from-concrete) that showed up in the queue was asked at 16:05UTC on March 19th.  The [next most recent first question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26161/do-i-have-to-remove-the-existing-6-fence-posts-to-install-an-8-metal-fence) was asked at 19:27UTC on the same day.

It is still showing answers, however.

I got confirmation in chat that the same thing is happening on [Ask Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com), [SF&Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/) and [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), so I guess it's network wide.

Comment: I've noticed now you can complete 40 per day rather than the usual 20.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

WELL IT IS NOW! ...and people are reviewing like crazy, holy christ you guys are clicking fast.

Comment: May I ask (if there was a problem)  what it was?

Comment: @Seth - we were excluding locked posts via a `p.ParentId In (...)`, when `ParentId` is null on questions, so it needed a simple `IsNull(p.ParentId, 0) In (...)` instead is all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was just fixed, there is now ~9K First Posts to review in the queue on StackOverflow, from what I could see all questions.

The daily limit for First Posts reviews was raised to 40 (from usual 20).