# Sudden spike in the number "First Posts" in the StackOverflow review queue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I was just looking at the review queue on Stackoverflow and there were zero "First Posts" to be reviewed. A minute later, there was suddenly 9.9k "First Posts" in the review queue. Is this a bug?

I completed 20 reviews, so it is not just the number being displayed that has a bug.

[image: large first post queue]

Comment: Not a duplicate in this case given Nick's answer below.

Comment: Looks like the 20 reviews per day limit is temporarily upped to 40.

Comment: lol for moments I though that I had just unlock some "feature" in SO and got rewarded with a bigger first post queue :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There was a bug by which [questions were not being added to the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173886/first-posts-review-queue-is-not-showing-first-questions), that bug [was just resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173892/135201) and the queue got the items it should have had.

It's being burned through at an incredible rate though, it won't be there long.

Comment: Aaaaand they're gone.  Hey, I have an idea! Can you take 10k posts from the close votes review queue and drop them in first posts?  ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard that's actually a great idea. I'd love to see that happen.