# Is the limit of First-Post reviews raised to 40?

Tags: discussion, review

As can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats) it looks like we can now review up to 40 first posts. As far as I remember it was 20 till recently.

Is it that the policy has been changed or the limit has been temporarily raised due to too many (3k+) pending for review ?

Comment: I always seem to miss these spikes :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a temporary change to handle the [sudden spike of posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173894) that flooded that review task.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information. I was pretty surprised to find some may question in the queue.

Comment: Have there really been 10,002 first post reviews *today*? http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats