# Sudden increase in First Post review count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-audits

When I usually do a review in SO, normally I gets less the 3 item in the First Post section, and some times no items. But, Today When try to review I got 2.6k items on First Post section.

And further I could be able to review more the 20 item today? Aren't there any restriction on no of item in First Post review?

Is it a bug? Why this sudden increase?

Comment: And [Is the limit of First-Post reviews raised to 40?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173919/is-the-limit-of-first-post-reviews-raised-to-40)

Comment: I was just about to ask that when I saw, 1.7k First Posts for review.

Comment: 4 hours later, all gone.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug, and for today only you get 40 reviews.

From last couple of days you noticed that in first post we only got first answers for review. and today we get around 10k first post (most are questions).

There was a bug and I think it is solved today so we get a lots of first post for review.