# Thank you for reviewing 20 First Posts today. But I reviewed 40?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

This looks like a bug (though minor) to me. The [First-Post Review link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) shows me

```
Thank you for reviewing 20 First Posts today; come back in xx hours to continue reviewing.
```

But the fact is I reviewed 40 posts today ([due to spike in First Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173894/sudden-spike-in-the-number-first-posts-in-the-stackoverflow-review-queue)). Such scenarios might be rare so this might have been missed by the QAs.

Comment: Since the [ability to review 40 posts is only temporay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173920/188276), this probably won't get fixed.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, if you have reviewed 40, you also have reviewed 20, so this is no bug.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Good one!

Comment: @DominicKexel That is why I think it is a minor bug. Still I think in the interest of making the site _perfect_ this can be considered for fixing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with changing this is the upping to 40 is a rare and automated measure for when the queues are abnormally high.  If we change the message to display this and you come back tomorrow when levels are normal the question then becomes: "why can't I review 40 like yesterday?"

I think leaving it as 20 in the message (which is technically correct) is the least confusing of the two.

Comment: Couldn't we simply print the actual number of post the user reviewed ? For a normal day it would be **20**, for a day like today, it would be **40**. So even if in the coming releases the decision is taken to increase the count of allowed reviews to **25**, the code will correctly print **25** without needing any change.

Comment: @Apurv - I addressed this *exactly* in the second sentence above. It's not the code, code's easy.  It's the confusion it causes.

Comment: What about just removing the number altogether?

Comment: @Troyen - then it doesn't really convey there *is* a limit, or the question becomes "what is the limit on reviews?" here on meta as well.  We *had* this question and confusion, that's why the message was added in the first place.

Comment: So we can only review 20 first posts regardless of reputation?