# "First post" weirdness

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When just entering unix.SE, I saw 95 (!) first posts, in CS.SE there were 12, 500 in Math.SE. I did see several posts there that I'm sure I saw for a few days, en I seem to remember reviewing some before. What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to a bug in First Posts queue.

See:

- [First Posts review queue is not showing first questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173886/181511)
- [Sudden spike in the number "First Posts" in the StackOverflow review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173894/181511)